# Getting a point in the local frame of a simulated robot

Tags: robotics, game-development, coordinate-transformation, kinematics, homogenous-transformation

This is for a robot simulation that I'm currently working on. 
If you look at the diagram provided, you'll see two co-ordinate frames. **Frame A**, **Frame B**; and you will find a point *p*.

Co-ordinate frame **A** is the world-frame, and frame **B** is the local frame for my robot (where the *x*-axis is the heading-direction of the robot, as per convention). The robot is able to rotate and drive around in the world.

My goal here is to find the point *p*, expressed in terms of frame **A**, and re-express it in terms of the frame **B**.

[image: My set-up]

The standard equation that I would use to implement this would be as follows:

```
point_in_frameB_x = point_in_frameA_x * cos(theta) - point_in_frameA_y * sin(theta) + t_x
point_in_frameB_y = point_in_frameA_x * sin(theta) + point_in_frameA_y * cos(theta) + t_y
```

Where `t_x` and `t_y` make up the translation transformation of frame **B** to frame **A**.

However, there are some complications here that prevent me from getting my desired results:

Since the robot can rotate around (with its default pose being with a heading direction north--and this has a rotation of 0 radians), I don't know how I would define `t_x` and `t_y` in the above code. Because if the robot has a heading direction (i.e. x-axis) parallel to the y-axis of frame **A**, the translation vector would be different from the situation where the robot has a heading direction parallel to the x-axis of frame **A**.

*You would notice that the transformation from frame **A** to frame **B** isn't straightforward. I'm using this convention simply because I'm implementing this simulator which uses this convention for its image-frame.*

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Follow [right hand rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-hand_rule) for assigning coordinate frames. In your picture axes of either frame A or frame B must be changed.

[image]

Comment: The question is, how would I determine t_x, t_y in order to change the co-ordinate frames? Especially when I'm rotating? I'm already using homogeneous co-ordinates (as would be clear from the pseudocode I posted).

Comment: Do you want to determine the pose of the robot (t_x, t_y, theta) ? How are you moving the robot ?